# Why I get division by zero for PostgreSQL v13? I suppose rows should be filtered out

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Running same query on different versions of PostgreSQL gives different result.

```sql
WITH t(a, b) AS (VALUES (1, 0))
SELECT a / b
  FROM t
 WHERE b <> 0;
```

On `v11.10` I get no rows as expected [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=838447f9300b55b1b1d30bef1f32fc81)
On `v13.1` I get `ERROR:  division by zero`
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=838447f9300b55b1b1d30bef1f32fc81)

Why I get division by zero for PostgreSQL `v13.1`? I suppose rows should be filtered out as it done for  `v11.10`

**UPD**
I think when we join, optimizer should not call lateral function sometimes (when it may) and save time:
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c7bb75d51392f99a4ee8deef14b27e0)

Comment: @GMB: your fiddle works without error. What do you mean about bug? it should or should rise `division by zero`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the order of evaluation is not what one would expect it to be: that is, one would expect that `0` denominators would be filtered out by the `where` clause before the computation in the `select` clause happens. Obviously the database chooses to do things differently.

You can, however, easily work around this with `nullif()`:

```
with t(a, b) as (values (1, 0))
select a / nullif(b, 0)
from t
where b <> 0;
```

This properly produce no rows.

I would tend qualifying this as a bug, or at least a regression. Playing around in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6ec28150eb44b3104c40726aec5e8d87), your original code works fine in versions 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10 and 11, but fails in versions 12 and 13.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to mail PostgreSQL hackers group

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I would be interested to read how they will assess this.

Comment: Reply from IRC: This is by intention. Required for constant-fold optimization

Comment: @jjanes answer explains this case much better then this one, it boils down to constant-folding and CTE-inlining.

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of PostgreSQL (starting in 12) look through your strange use of the constant **single row** VALUES list to see the constant-folding opportunity.  But it folds the division constant before it folds the WHERE constant, and so trips over the error.

In 11, you would still get the error in other similar places, like:

```
select 1/0 from pgbench_accounts where aid < -100;
```

This can be annoying if you are trying to come up with a very simple example not useful in its own right, but just to test something else.  But I just chalk it up to "Play stupid games, win stupid prizes", and find some other way to test what I want to test.  In your case, you can just make the CTE be materialized.

```
WITH t(a, b) AS materialized (VALUES (1, 0))
SELECT a / b            
  FROM t
 WHERE b <> 0;
```

Comment: Some guru on IRC advice me to use `offset 0` and lateral join for cases when expression is function: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=07894c7fe68fb7a421814504865e43b5

Comment: I have found if I create second row, then there is also no constant-folding: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61b443c981899c6dc8e35f64a3974a49 So I highlight `single row`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: there is also no error if you use a real table, rather than a CTE: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=937b1f0e97b5102c92b8adc14b47ff43